# How to group by three column using conditions in Pandas(Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi so I am currently working with a data frame which has the following Columns:

User_id(has more than 30 types of repeated user id's):1,22,33,3,1,222,1,3 and so on

Column1(has two categories):A,B,A,B and so on

Column2(has two categories):BB,CC,BB,CC and so on..

Date: 2010-01-09,2010-01-03 and so on..

Now what I am trying to do is that I need to get min date when column1=A,Column2=BB for a particular user id(like say 1)
Also doing the same thing for all combinations like if Column1=B,Column 2=BB etc.

PS:This is using Python(Pandas,Numpy).
Thanks and looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to do is group by `Column2`, `Column1` and `id` and get the min of the date column:

```
mins = df.groupby(['Column2', 'Column1','id']).Date.min()
```

if you want to get the info for only one particular user id you can filter the df beforehand

```
df = df[df.id==1]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, that worked perfectly.Also I wanted to know if its possible to create another column with these date values in the same data frame?